# add zbar to my application

Tags: java, android, zbar

I whould like to add the zbar scanner to my simple application.

I just created a new project on eclipse.

```
  activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:text="@string/ButtonScan" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java

```
package com.example.touchak;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.touchak"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.touchak.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

   </manifest>
```

So i wanna when i click on the scan button the application will scan a QR code.

So please help me to add the zbar scanner on my application.

Thank yuou so munch

So i was used the OnClickListner on my application like this

```
package com.example.x;

     import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.widget.Button;
     import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

       public class SimplestButtonActivity extends Activity {

Button button1,button2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simplest_button);
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, main2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }



    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, main3.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
}
    });

        }

    }
```

But how can i call the zbar scanner when i click on the scan button?

Answer (score 0):

Download this project from

https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner

And Import the library & Sample/demo project.

And there you go.

Comment: Yes, i was import the library but i when i click on the scan button there are nothing, no action, and i don't know where is the problem

Comment: See this https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner/blob/master/examples/ZBarScannerDemo/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: @user3185474 Worked it or still having prob?

Comment: So i was used OnClickListner in my app like this

Comment: i was used OnClickListner in my application, see my question i was add my OnClickListner file

Comment: Don't do your own listener. Instead create a new project & import the library & sample & just copy paste their code into yours without any modification of yours.